# How to recognize DICOM files? C#

Tags: c#, list, file, foreach, dicom

I have a folder with files, but not all of them are DICOM files and I need to recognize which one is a DICOM.

My first decision was to create foreach loop where I am checking Extension:

```
foreach (var item in fileList.Where(x => x.Extension == ".dcm"))
        {
        }
```

But not all of them have ".dcm" and some of them do not, but they are DICOM.

I am using fo-dicom nuget package, but didn't find the answer there.

My question is:
How to check all files for DICOM?

I know that Dicom file has 128 bytes free and then the last 4 bytes for "DICM", but how I can check this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using fo-dicom, then you can use the built in method `DicomFile.HasValidHeader(filename)`, that returns true or false.

this method checks for those magic bytes but also checks for older version of dicom, where the 128 bytes are not present.

Comment: @Hans Kesting Thank you for your answer. Yes, I found this method today, but I'm getting a list of files, not just one file and I'm using foreach. Maybe you know then, how I can put this method in foreach?

Comment: @Sanktos I just fixed a typo, the real answer is by gofal3

Comment: if you have `foreach(var filename in fileList)`, then *inside* that foreach you can check the separate files. Or even with LiNQ: `foreach(var dicomfile in fileList.Where(f => DicomFile.HasValidHeader(f))` - then you process just the valid files

Answer (score 2):

You can just skip the first 128 bytes of the file and read the next 4 bytes and compare them with the ASCII codes for "DICM", for example:

```
byte[] dicomPrefix    = new byte[4];
byte[] expectedPrefix = "DICM".Select(c => (byte)c).ToArray();

using (var file = File.OpenRead("your filepath here"))
{
    if (file.Length >= 132)
    {
        file.Position = 128; // Skip first 128 bytes.
        file.Read(dicomPrefix, 0, dicomPrefix.Length);

        if (dicomPrefix.SequenceEqual(expectedPrefix))
        {
            // It's a DICOM file.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ Matthew Watson Thank you for your answer. I am using Windows Forms. I have an error with "using".  This feature is not available in C# 7.3. What can I do instead of using it? I'm sorry, I'm new in C#.

Comment: `using(var file = File.OpenRead("your filepath here")){ your code here }`

Comment: @Sanktos I've edited my answer to use the old-style `using`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that I found a solution for my question:

```
foreach (FileInfo f in fileList)
{
    bool isDicom = DicomFile.HasValidHeader(f.FullName);
    if (isDicom)
    {
    }
}
```